# React Router fetch data on route change for a component without props

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In Switch router scenario,how do we  fetch fresh data from the server, after coming back to a already mounted component which doesn't have any props. I went through many posts before asking this. All posts suggest use componentWillRecieveUpdate. This life cycle hook will never be called if the component doesn't have any props. I even tried the getDerivedStatefromProps

What is best option to deal with scenarios like this.?

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

// import react router
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Menu />
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/help" component={Help} />
              <Route exact path="/" component={OverView} />
              <Route component={OverView} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

class Menu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/help">Help</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">OverView</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

class Help extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Some help</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class OverView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

 getDerivedStatefromProps(prevprops,prevstate, ){
   //Even this will also not be called
 }

 componentWillRecieveUpdate(newprops)
 {
     //I dont recieve a call to this when come back from help
 }

  render() {
    //can we fetch data here and save in the state
    // and re-render. Will this cause any issues
    return <div> How to return fetch data</div>;
  }
}

render(<Application />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBRjEw

Comment: Hi, just wanted to point out that `recieve` is actually spelled `receive` , which might already explain why that method never gets called. However, I looked up the API documentation for `React.Component` and cannot find `componentWillReceiveUpdate` there. It's either `componentWillUpdate` or `componentWillReceiveProps`. I haven't found a combination of both of them. The methods are also deprecated and shouldn't be used according to the following page: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html - There's also a bit of explanation why you shouldn't use these methods anymore

Comment: its a typo in the stackoverflow question. I did check that.  codepen.io/anon/pen/VBRjEw

Comment: Hi Srikan, is it right to say you would like the overview component to fetch data each time the route is visited? So, the user goes from help to overview, then data needs to be fetched again. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I have been digging in your code a little bit, please have a notice that your component is mounting every time, it's not one time mounted as you claimed.

please read the React Router [doc](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component) to understand more.

You can see it in the [Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejXgBy)

```
class OverView extends React.Component{
  constructor(props,context) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('mounted');
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render');
    return(<div> How to return fetch data</div>)
  }
}
```